# Multiple outputs printed slowly at the same time

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

As it's stated in the title, I have N strings (let's say 3) and they go one after the other like:

```
"string1"
"string2"
"string3"
```

With the help of 'sleep' we can make the string get printed out slowly, symbol by symbol, BUT I want to have each of them printed slowly AT THE SAME TIME. Is it possible to do such a thing?

Problem - lvl.'Advanced': Can I make 3 tkinter buttons with text in them printed like that? Or maybe it'd be better to create labels with such text-effect (if possible) and instantly replace them with 3 buttons with the same words?

Comment: What does "print slowly" mean? Are you asking how to display a string by showing one character at a time with a delay between each character?

Comment: Can you add sample code (or code you already have) and, if possible, an image of what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to create a label that slowly reveals one character at a time (ie: first you see "s", then "st", then "str", etc).

That can be cone by creating a custom label class, and using `after` to slowly reveal the text. Each time the function `reveal_text` is called, it pops one character off of the list of remaining characters, appends it to the characters already displayed, and then arranges for itself to be called again in half a second.

For example:

```
class SlowLabel(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Label.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.text = self.cget("text")
        self.configure(text="")

        self.reveal_text()

    def reveal_text(self):
        if len(self.text) > 0:
            text = self.cget("text") + self.text[0]
            self.configure(text=text)
            self.text = self.text[1:]
            self.after(500, self.reveal_text)
```

You can use this class exactly like you would use a normal label:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
for text in ("string1", "string2", "string3"):
    label = SlowLabel(root, text=text, width=20, anchor="w")
    label.pack(side="top", fill="x")
```

If you prefer buttons rather than labels, just inherit from `tk.Button` rather than `tk.Label`.

Comment: That's what I need, though I (as a beginner) still don't understand if this prints text in first label, then in second, then in third etc. or do all labels get filled in at the same time? The second question is, do I just have to change both instances of "tk.Label" to "tk.Button" or do I need to change any other piece of code?

Comment: @AlexF: Instead of asking a question, run the code and see what it does.